# ASP.NET GRids and DeveloperExpress ASPx Grid - Hooking up to a webservice

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Is it possible to use the asp.net server controls e.g. grid, repeater etc in conjunction with a webservice? I'm wanting to populate the grid from a webservice datasource and then save changes using a webservice.

Is it possible to use the DeveloperExpress Grid in conjunction with a webservice?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can.

You can create a webmethod which returns a datasource for e.g. a generic list containing objects of a serializable class, which can then be bound to the grid/DevExpress grid.